# Remove any digit only in first N characters

Tags: regex, r

I'm looking for a regular expression to catch all digits in the first 7 characters in a string.

This string has 12 characters:

```
A12B345CD678
```

I would like to remove `A` and `B` only since they are within the first 7 chars (`A12B345`) and get

```
12345CD678
```

So, the `CD678` should not be touched. My current solution in R:

```
paste(paste(str_extract_all(substr("A12B345CD678",1,7), "[0-9]+")[[1]],collapse=""),substr("A12B345CD678",8,nchar("A12B345CD678")),sep="‌​")
```

It seems too complicated. I split the string at 7 as described, match any digits in the first 7 characters and bind it with the rest of the string.

Looking for a general answer, my current solution is to split the first 7 characters and just match all digits in this sub string.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Your question doesn't make any sense to me. `12345CD678` is more than 7 characters, even more than 7 digits - and what do you mean by `the first E-F`?

Comment: Your example is confusing. What is "first E-F 7 characters"? Why do you also match CD even though they are not digits?

Comment: Please post your current solution.

Comment: To be more clear, A12B345CD678 has 12 characters. I want to match all digits in the first 7 characters, so CD678 would not be touched.. My current solution in R: paste(paste(str_extract_all(substr("A12B345CD678",1,7), "[0-9]+")[[1]],collapse=""),substr("A12B345CD678",8,nchar("A12B345CD678")),sep="") which seems to be to complicated. I split the string at 7 as descriped, match any digets in the first 7 characters and bind it with the rest of the string.

Comment: Seems like you need variable length lookbehind [like this demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5e.%7b0%2c6%7d)%5cD&i=A12B345CD678&o=m): `(?<=^.{0,6})\D` which is not available in R regex flavor. [This could work](https://regex101.com/r/uS0oF0/1) with `perl=TRUE` but looks even worse to maintain.

Comment: I see this is more complex then I thought, thank you for your efforts bobble bubble

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use the known [SKIP-FAIL regex trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) to match all the rest of the string beginning with the 8th character, and only match non-digit characters within the first 7 with a lookbehind:

```
s <- "A12B345CD678"
gsub("(?<=.{7}).*$(*SKIP)(*F)|\\D", "", s, perl=T)
## => [1] "12345CD678"
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/coAIXq)

The `perl=T` is required for this regex to work. The regex breakdown:

- `(?<=.{7}).*$(*SKIP)(*F)` - matches any character but a newline (add `(?s)` at the beginning if you have newline symbols in the input), as many as possible (`.*`) up to the end (`$`, also `\\z` might be required to remove final newlines), but only if preceded with 7 characters (this is set by the lookbehind `(?<=.{7})`). The `(*SKIP)(*F)` verbs make the engine omit the whole matched text and advance the regex index to the position at the end of that text.
- `|` - or...
- `\\D` - a non-digit character.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/wA4vU0/1).

Comment: Great idea thought out of the box Stribiżew!

Comment: Works perfect, thank you especially for the explanation.

Comment: Just in case there are newlines, here is how the regex would look like: [`"(?s)(?<=.{7}).*\\z(*SKIP)(*F)|\\D"`](https://ideone.com/CXQkZE).

Answer (score 5):

The regex solution is cool, but I'd use something easier to read for maintainability. E.g.

```
library(stringr)

str_sub(s, 1, 7) = gsub('[A-Z]', '', str_sub(s, 1, 7))
```

Comment: should [A-Z] be [A-Za-z]?

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a simple negative lookbehind:

```
s <- "A12B345CD678"
gsub("(?<!.{7})\\D", "", s, perl=T)
```